# Screen turns background colour when clicking on EditText inside ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling to figure out this weird bug for a day and a half. Whenever I click on an `EditText` that is a child of an `ExpandableListView`, the screen gets obscured such that the user is unable to see what is being typed, as shown in the gif below: \n
https://giant.gfycat.com/GenuineUnluckyHyrax.mp4

I started digging into the Hierarchy View to see what could be doing this, here is a screenshot of it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AW6p.png

To me it looks like the Toolbar up top is extending downwards to cover the screen, which is odd because it doesnt do that on other activities that contain `EditText` widgets. I've checked that parent views are using "`wrap_content`" for height instead of "`match_parent`" as well, except for my `DrawerLayout` which must `match_parent`. Below is the layout code for the activity:

```
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <!--SideBar views -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/sidebarColor">
                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:id="@+id/qwedit_sidebar_elv"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:indicatorLeft="?
android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
                        android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp">
                    </ExpandableListView>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!--MainView views -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_elv"
                        android:layout_width="930dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:indicatorLeft="?
android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"
                        android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
                </ExpandableListView>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nvView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the `EVL`'s group layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_sidebar_elv_parent_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Category"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_elv_parent_status"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_warning"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_elv_parent_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Score"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/qwedit_elv_item_score_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_badView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/badScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_badTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Bad"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_mediocreView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/mediocreScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_mediumTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Mediocre"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_goodView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/goodScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_goodTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Good"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_wcView"
        android:layout_width="232.5dp"
        android:layout_height="145.3dp"
        android:background="@color/worldclassScore">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qwedit_main_worldclassTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="World Class"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<EditText
    android:layout_width="930dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/qwedit_elv_item_score_container"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Comments"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm assuming that this is all due to the layouts, but here is the `CustomExpandableListAdapter` that I wrote for it just in case the answer lies in how the views are being inflated:

```
/**
 * Created by Tadhg on 9/8/2017.
 */

public class QwEditMainCustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

//Values inits
private int categoryScore;
private int subCategoryScore;
private boolean completedCategory;
private boolean completedSubCategory;

// ChildView views
private View badScoreView;
private View mediocreScoreView;
private View goodScoreView;
private View worldclassScoreView;
TextView badScoreTextView;
TextView mediocreScoreTextView;
TextView goodScoreTextView;
TextView worldClassScoreTextView;
EditText questionCommentEditText;

public QwEditMainCustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                             HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail
            .get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.qwedit_main_elv_item, null);
    }
    // ChildView views
    badScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_badView);
    mediocreScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_mediocreView);
    goodScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_goodView);
    worldclassScoreView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_wcView);
    badScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_badTextView);
    mediocreScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_mediumTextView);
    goodScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_goodTextView);
    worldClassScoreTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_worldclassTextView);

    // TODO: TextView score subcategory setters

    badScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 1;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#eca9a7"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
        }
    });

    mediocreScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 2;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7d6a6"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
        }
    });

    goodScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 3;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#addbad"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0275d8"));
        }
    });

    worldclassScoreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO: add logic to change score
            subCategoryScore = 4;
            badScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d9534f"));
            mediocreScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0ad4e"));
            goodScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5cb85c"));
            worldclassScoreView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80baeb"));
        }
    });
    /**
     * Use variables categoryScore and subCategoryScore to update scores
     */
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.qwedit_main_elv_group, null);
    }

    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.qwedit_main_elv_parent_title);

    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() { return false; }

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) { return true; }
}
```

Any points or tips would be great. I think that this may be due to the number of views in my hierarchy (or at least a subissue of it), but I'm not sure and am relatively new to Android Development.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, simply adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden"` caused the ActionBar to not expand to 996px when the `EditText` gained focus